# App works on emulator but not on device?

Tags: java, android

MyApp simply doesn't launch. It starts to open and just shuts off. I am guessing I have screwed something here in the Build when Google Developers asked me to change the Code Version, although I am not sure. Any help is deeply appreciated. I am positive I am making some very basic mistake,although I cannot put my finger on it. It works perfectly on a Nexus Emulator though.

Earlier it was just a splash screen which led to a webview. Then I added a page with two options(Buttons) to choose the webview after the splash animation. Thats the change that I made although if it is working on Emulator I am not sure if the activity code is the issdue.

Build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.utilities.livegoldsilverusd"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Manifest.XML

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.utilities.livegoldsilverusd">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/newicon"
        android:label="LiveMCXRates"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/newicon"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Splash screen -->

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Welcome_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".options"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Bitcoin"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!isConnected(MainActivity.this)) buildDialog(MainActivity.this).show();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Let's Make Money! WooHoo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        {
            myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://viralonworld.com/m1/runtmfultb.php");
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if((mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting())) return true;
        else return false;
        } else
        return false;
    }

    public AlertDialog.Builder buildDialog(Context c) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
        builder.setMessage("You need to have Mobile Data or wifi to access this. Press ok to Exit");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                finish();
            }
        });

        return builder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Options.Java

```
package com.utilities.livegoldsilverusd;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.utilities.livegoldsilverusd.R.id.button1;
import static com.utilities.livegoldsilverusd.R.layout.activity_options;



public class options extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_options);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(options.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(options.this, Bitcoin.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Bitcoin.java

```
package com.utilities.livegoldsilverusd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;


public class Bitcoin extends Activity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!isConnected(Bitcoin.this)) buildDialog(Bitcoin.this).show();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(Bitcoin.this, "Let's Make Money! WooHoo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        {
            myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://bitcointicker.co/");
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if ((mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()))
                return true;
            else return false;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public AlertDialog.Builder buildDialog(Context c) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
        builder.setMessage("You need to have Mobile Data or wifi to access this. Press ok to Exit");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                finish();
            }
        });

        return builder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_options.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="146dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:onClick="goToMainActivity"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="Live MCX Rates"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:onClick="goTobitcoin"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:text="BitCoin"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_bitcoin.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.utilities.livegoldsilverusd.MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does your device have the minimum required OS version?

Comment: I just added a couple of activities to an existing project. The previous worked fine. So should this. Isn't it?

Comment: You have declared 2 different Activities as Main by intent in your manifest, maybe that's the problem? I think there should only be one…

Comment: could you point me to it? in the code

Comment: See, in the manifest file, you got `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">` and `<activity android:name=".Welcome_Activity">`, each one has an intent filter that makes it be the MAIN activity. The real MainActivity is declared as DEFAULT and the WelcomeActivity is declared as LAUNCHER, so maybe that is causing confusion. Which one is the one to be started on app launch?
It is this line `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` that occurs twice, but usually has to be unique in the manifest

Comment: But the same worked fine earlier...If at all what should I change it to...? Also, How will it not affect the launch in emulator?

Comment: Just try removing the intent filter from the welcome activity, maybe that brings up anything working. If it worked before, then what exactly did you add that could have caused the issue?

Comment: I put the intent filter because welcome activity is a splash animation..it needs to launch before Main Activity. I in fact just added two buttons after splash where user can choose to click on either and go the relevant webpage. How many problems with code can there be where the app works on emulator but not on device?

Comment: It is giving me an error "DEFAULT activity not found" if I remove intent..and I don't want MainActivity to be launcher..so the error makes sense...

Comment: The splash screen is not shown on device but on emulated one? Hmm… Does it work again without the buttons? Maybe it is the device… How does it differ from the emulated one? There must be any differences

Comment: No No...on the device...the App just doesn't launch..it crashes as soon as it launched...on Emulator everything is cool...Splash animation first..then a page with two buttons...click on either to go to webview..thats it...It seems a problem with Build or Manifest

Comment: shall I post the code for other activities as well?

Comment: Please do so, maybe others will get involved, too. Just clearly point out what you added before it stopped working on the device.

Comment: ok I did put in all the code...please see if you can find something

Comment: Have you really changed the gradle file when you added the buttons?

Comment: No I just changed the VersionCode from 2 to 3and Version Name from1 to 1.3 for listing at App store..nothing else.

Comment: No (further) idea… I assume you have uninstalled the version 1.2 manually before flashing the new version.

Comment: I downloaded from App store as well..That also crashes....How do I ask/share this to a coding champion here?

Comment: Gain reputation and reward some, don't know another way. Flag this question or raise attention in another way.

Comment: Hey man...I fixed it....Apparently..I had chosen a Non-Opaque color in my Styles.XML....PFFFFTT! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is due to we are setting content view of activity_main, which loads a layout file that contains a  WebView with android:id="@+id/myWebView...
The problem solves when setting WebView in activity_main;
Write this in your activity_main.I think problem will be solved...

```
 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Also modify your Manifest.xml by making MainActivity as launcher instead of Welcome

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.utilities.livegoldsilverusd">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/newicon"
    android:label="LiveMCXRates"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/newicon"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Splash screen -->

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".options"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Bitcoin"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```